# Stop calling functions in Dispatcher method WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, dispatcher, dispatch-async

I have a WPF project. In Form1 when click a button I'm calling continueProcess() method within a background worker.

```
    private void BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            continueProcess();
        });
    }
```

Within continueProcess() method I want to open another form and close the Form1.

```
if(condition == true)
{
dosomework();
}
else
{
openNewForm();
closeForm1();
}
someOtherFunctions();
```

But in here in else statement after opening new form , still again coming to the someOtherFunctions() .

I don't want to execute any method in Form1, after closing that.
I know this is happening because of BackGroundWorker or Dispatcher.Invoke method.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `return` statement as below:

```
void continueProcess()
{

    if(condition == true)
    {
        dosomework();
    }
    else
    {
        openNewForm();
        closeForm1();
        return; // <----------- add me!
    }
    someOtherFunctions();
}
```

That will prevent any further statements from executing in the method.

By the way, `Dispatcher.Invoke` is not a *"background worker"*.  All you are doing is queing the method call to the Windows Message Pump to be processed by the UI thread - the same one you were currently using!  It's also a synchonous call, so `Dispatcher.Invoke` won't return until `continueProcess` does.

Comment: What? Better move `someOtherFunctions();` into the `if` block.

Comment: @Clemens I thought of that, but considering OP is already not showing all his code I thought it best to do it this way.  He might have something else in there.  I also don't want to refactor code when it's not that necessary

Comment: Sure, obviously move everything after the else into the if block.

Comment: I added the return; But still someOtherFunctions(); getting execute.

Comment: What I meant in my question is im calling dispatcher.invoke within a back ground worker. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @Tom no chance after return, I guess you might have assigned  BgWorker.DoWork += BgWorker_DoWork   two times .